# Solve linear system with restrictions for unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'd like to know how to find the solution "$x$" to a linear system of equations of the form:

$Ax=b$

Where "$A$" is an invertible square matrix containing the coefficients of the system, "$x$" is a column vector containing the unknowns and "$b$" is another column vector containing the constant terms;

in which each of the unknowns must be contained in a known domain:

$xmin_i \le x_i \le xmax_i$        for $i=1,2..n$ ($n$ = size of the system)

(domain limits don't have to be different for different $x_i$ )

and in which each of the constant terms $b_i$ must be contained in a known domain:

$bmin_i \le b_i \le bmax_i$       for $i=1,2..n$ ($n$ = size of the system)

(domain limits don't have to be different for different $b_i$ )

I don't know in which field of mathematics find the solution or at least a hint to the problem.

I have thought of using a "brute force" method by discretizing the domain for the constant terms  and thus solving the system over and over again for different "$b$" vectors, among the discretized possibles, and then checking if the solution "$x$" for that particular "$b$" matches the requirements $xmin_i \le x_i \le xmax_i$

But in that method, too many "$b$" vectors are generated if the size of the system is a bit big and is not possible to compute all the possibles "$b$"

Thank you very much

Comment: you can solve the linear system first, and then filter out answers which are not within the range.